# Java access to the list, which is in the map

Tags: java, csv

When parsing a csv file I added each column adds to the list, and then each list to the `map`. In each map the key is the first line of the list.

```
        CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader("plik.csv"),';');
        CSVReader ile = new CSVReader(new FileReader("plik.csv"),';');

        int columnCount=0;
        String[] header = ile.readNext(); // assuming first read

        if (header != null) {                     // and there is a (header) line
              columnCount = header.length;       // get the column count
        }


        HashMap<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

        List content = reader.readAll();
        String[] row;
        String key;
        int column=0;

        for(int i=0; i <columnCount-1; i++) {
            List<String> lista = new ArrayList<String>();
                key=null;
            for (Object object : content) {

                row = (String[]) object;
                if (column== 0) {
                    key = row[i];
                }
                if (kolumna != 0) {

                    lista.add(row[i]);
                    map.put(key, lista);
                }
                kolumna++;
            }
            kolumna=0;
        }
```

After this operation, I would like to have access to the possibility of iteration on each of these lists.

I wanted to do this using

```
for (String q: map.keySet ()) {
             System.out.println (q + "-" + map.get (q));
         }
```

But the result is that each list is shown on szytwno in each line. I do not have access to individual items in the list that I would like to throw eg. To the drop-down swing.

Output:

```
Datum - [07.10.2014, 07.10.2014, 07.10.2014]
ProzessID - [1180804, 1180804, 335605]
```

Key: `Datum`, `ProzessID`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use map.entrySet() instead:

```
      for (Entry<String, List<String>> entry : map.entrySet())
      {
          System.out.println(entry.getKey() + ":");
          for (String s : entry.getValue()){
              System.out.println(s);
          }
      }
```

Comment: This already tried. The data are displayed in the same way. I would like to list items display them one under the other and were not separated by `,` and `[`. Maybe I need to do a loop in the loop? So that I can control the iterations of the same list. He wants the data that is on the list to add to the JComboBox. So that you have a choice of `1180804` or `1180804` or `335605`.  And not the entire row `[1180804, 1180804, 335605]`.

Comment: the brackets and colons are made by the toString() method from the list. if you want to display them differently you need to access each item in the list itself.

You know that a ComboBox has a addAll method?
comboBox.getItems().addAll(entry.getValue());

Comment: Sorry, just saw you are using a JComboBox and not the JavaFX one, then iterate in the loop over the elemente in the list

Comment: Tobi: But How to display it without brackets? I tried `entry.getValue (). ToString ()` but none of that. I would like to get to each item in the list so that I showed in the console: Key and underneath additional list items. With the combobox does not want to do anything yet. I want to be able to control the iteration of the list.

Comment: That's exactly what it was! Has this loop can check the size of the list? Now I would like for each key maps to create a separate combobox. I can easily do this loop so?

Comment: you can do whatever you want there, the entry.getValue() is your List<string> item.
you can create a combobox in the first loop and in the second add the items

Comment: OK. How to check the length of the list?

Comment: `entry.getValue().size()`